# JVisualVM is unable to connect to process using the --openpid argument

Tags: java, jconsole, jvisualvm, java-service-wrapper, procrun

I have an application that is running as a win-service (using [Apache-Procrun](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/procrun.html)). I want to monitor that application with JVisualVM. I've used the commandline argument `--openpid <PID>` without success, ironically the old JConsole managed to connect to that application.

[image: JVisualVM vs JConsole 0:1]

I also checked all issues with the `%TMP%\hsperfdata_username` -Directory that are described in the JVisualVM-[Trouble Shooting Guide](http://visualvm.java.net/troubleshooting.html). Its all well.

How can i get the JVisualVM to monitor my app?

Comment: Maybe this helps
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031359/jvisualvm-doesnt-list-certain-java-processes]

Comment: Okay i guess this is a bug, so i opened a ticket at: http://java.net/jira/browse/VISUALVM-537

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JVisualVM is not able to connect to a win-service using the `--openpid <PID>` argument! The old JConsole can this only in WinXP because of a [Bug](http://java.net/jira/browse/VISUALVM-537?focusedCommentId=351488&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#action_351488). The alternative is to specify a JMX Agent for the service.

This VM Arguments have to be passed to the prunsrv.exe

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3333 \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false \
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false \
```

For more detail take a look at: [Connecting to JMX Agents Explicitly](http://visualvm.java.net/jmx_connections.html)

Comment: You may also need to add -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=3333